# Why I am getting the NoReverseMatch error and how can I solve it?

Tags: django, django-urls

Here is my code:

views.py

```
def book(request, flight_id):
    try:
        passenger_id = int(request.POST["passenger"])
        passenger = Passengers.objects.get(pk=passenger_id)
        flight = Flights.objects.get(pk=flight_id)
    except KeyError:
        return render(request, 'flights/error.html', {'message':'No Selection'})
    except Flights.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'flights/error.html', {'message':'No Flight'})
    except Passengers.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'flights/error.html', {'message': 'No Passengers'})

    passenger.flights.add(flight)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('flight', args=(flight_id,)))
```

template

```
<h2>Add a Passenger</h2>
{% if non_passengers %}
<form action="{% url 'book' flight.id %}" method="post">
    <select name="passenger">
    {% for passenger in non_passengers %}
    <option value="passenger.id">{{ passenger }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Book Flight"/>

</form>
{% else %}
   <div>No Passengers to add</div>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
   path('<int:flight_id>', views.flight, name='flight'),
   path('<int:flight_id>/book', views.book, name='book')
```

it shows me an error like this:

> NoReverseMatch at /1
>    Reverse for 'book' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[0-9]+)/book$']

Comment: there is no data coming through `flight.id`. You need to share your view

Comment: Now please check i have been add views

Comment: Is this the `'flights/error.html'` template?

Comment: The line <form action="{% url 'book' flight.id %}" method="post"> is causing the issue, flight.id is not a valid integer

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. I corrected the issue, what I did was, added app_name = "flights" in url.py and added it to views.py 'flights:flight'

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('flights:flight', args=(flight_id,)))
```

And also flight.html should be like this. (Added flights:book to form action )

```
<form action="{% url 'flights:book' flight.id %}" method="post">
```